# html5 video fails to load on chrome - sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

I have a weird problem.
I have a rather straight forward html5 video tag of an mp4 on AWS cloudfront

Sometimes, the video just doesn't load. Stays black and play doesn't do anything.
Sometimes it loads perfectly

Happens only on chrome, on Safari it's OK

Any caching issues I should try and avoid?

Comment: It's definately this problem https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234779

Comment: I have the exact same issue, and it is a result of the link Boaz references above.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tip that might help:

First clear your cookie and browsing history in google setting.

If that doesn't work, you can try disable hardware acceleration:

1. Go to chrome://settings
2. Scroll down to the system section.
3. Under system section, and turn off Use hardware acceleration when available.
4. restart chrome.

This will solve your problem.

The link is as follow:

[https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-embedded-videos-not-playing-google-chrome/#:~:text=To%20fix%20the%20problem%2C%20the,acceleration%20in%20Chrome's%20Advanced%20Settings.&text=Next%2C%20scroll%20down%20near%20the,to%20see%20if%20it%20works](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/fix-embedded-videos-not-playing-google-chrome/#:%7E:text=To%20fix%20the%20problem%2C%20the,acceleration%20in%20Chrome%27s%20Advanced%20Settings.&text=Next%2C%20scroll%20down%20near%20the,to%20see%20if%20it%20works).

Good Luck!